# Unit integration tests, system tests with node js, express, javascript

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, automated-tests, integration-testing

I am very new with testing , I have built a web app with node js, ejs, express . The web app has 10 different ejs files and for each file, there is a script linked to a .js file.

I need to test the 10 programs with unit , integration and system testing, I am using jest

the modules function on their own and they are not connected to each other

Is it possible to perform unit tests on chunks of code on a SINGLE .JS FILE, for example functions referring to them as units and is it possible to test these functions with variables or other connected functions in the SAME FILE referring to this as an integration test??

I am not sure if an integration test requires me to have a separate file with units for example functions and I must import them to another file in order to test integration with other units....?

I hope that was clear..
Thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: Depends on the file. Why did you end with single file, considering that Node is modular environment? This may prevent you from performing anything but e2e.

Comment: are you suggesting to use 2 scripts file for each ejs file???

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you provide a concise example of what your case looks like? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean